# How can I compare a non-existing JavaScript object to undefined without getting a Reference Error?

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I want to boolean to come out of this expression

```
(task === undefined);
```

where `task` is arbitrary and doesn’t appear in the code at all.

However, when I run this in rhino, I get a reference Error. I WANT TRUE

Why don’t I get true?

I want to check if a particular variable has been defined. How do I do it then if this doesn't work?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use this:

```
(typeof task === "undefined")
```

When you use `(task === undefined)`, Javascript needs to find the value of `task` to see if it is the same as `undefined`, but it can't look up the name because it doesn't exist, giving you the reference error.  `typeof` is special in that it can safely return the type of a name that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you! Why doesn’t JavaScript just declare task undefined, since it is literally undefined?

Comment: As I mentioned, you can't use the name `task` if it is undefined, it will raise an exception as you have seen.  `typeof` is special.  And Javascript did declare it undefined, it did it by raising the error!

Comment: @Fawkes5: there's a difference between "variable exists but has value `undefined`" and "variable doesn't exist at all".

Comment: Because `undefined` is an actual value, which is evaluated as false. If you haven't declared the variable first like `var foo;` then the variable doesn't have an `undefined` value assigned to it, therefor you have to check if it's type is `undefined` to really check if it exists. That's why you use quotes around `"undefined"` because it's a string.

Comment: what if reference was declared but never assigned... like `var task;` this will also be undefined

Answer (score 12):

**Addendum** to the accepted answer to understand why it doesn't work with some examples you can try yourself in a javascript console.

Comparing directly with undefined type only works if the variable exist. Below is the output you'll get from the Google Chrome browser:

```
> task === undefined
  ReferenceError: task is not defined
```

However if the **variable exists** it will work:

```
// continued from above
> var task
  undefined
> task === undefined
  true
```

This is the reason why you should use `typeof` solution instead because it will work in **all** cases without throwing errors (and breaking the execution of javascript code).

```
// continued from above
> typeof notavariable === 'undefined'
  true
> typeof task === 'undefined'
  true
```

Note that you don't need the `typeof` check in some cases, such as the properties in a object literal:

```
// continued from above
> var obj = {}
  undefined
> obj.test === undefined
  true
> obj.test = 1
  1
> obj.test === undefined
  false
```

This is because properties in an object behave more like values in an associative array:

```
// continued from above
> obj["test"]
  1
> obj["test"] === undefined
  false
```

However you can't always be sure this is a case in a function where you have no control over the argument input:

```
// continued from above
> function TestFunc(arg1) { console.log(arg1) }
  undefined
> TestFunc(notavariable)
  ReferenceError: notavariable is not defined
> TestFunc(task)
  undefined
  undefined
> TestFunc(obj["lol"])
  undefined
  undefined
```

Hope this exercise helps you out to understand the why's of this comparison.

Comment: Thanks @Spoike, this was as helpful as it was old! Haha.